# twitter spfx web part

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

This is the [origin example](https://github.com/OlivierCC/spfx-40-fantastics/wiki/Tweets-Feed) I tried to imlement with Spfx&reactJs webpart.
it looks working except when I edit the account(in editor pane), it doesnt affected till I reload the webpart also tweet limit not works.

webpart.tsx:

```
export default class Twitter extends React.Component<ITwitterProperties, IWebPartState> {
  private twttr: any;
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    debugger
    var innerHtml:any;
    if (this.props.account == null || this.props.account == '' || this.props.account == undefined) {
      var error = `
        <div class="ms-MessageBar">
          <div class="ms-MessageBar-content">
            <div class="ms-MessageBar-icon">
              <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--Info"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="ms-MessageBar-text">
              ${strings.ErrorSelectAccount}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      `;
      innerHtml=error;
    }
    else
    {
    var dataChrome = '';
    if (this.props.footer === false)
      dataChrome += "nofooter ";
    if (this.props.header === false)
      dataChrome += "noheader ";
    if (this.props.borders === false)
      dataChrome += "noborders ";
    if (this.props.scrollbars === false)
      dataChrome += "noscrollbar ";
    if (this.props.transparent === true)
      dataChrome += "transparent ";
    var limit = '';
    if (this.props.autoLimit === false)
      limit = 'data-tweet-limit="' + this.props.limit + '"';

    innerHtml = '<a class="twitter-timeline" data-link-color="' + this.props.linkColor + '" data-border-color="' + this.props.borderColor + '" height="' + this.props.height + '" width="' + this.props.width + '" ' + limit + ' data-chrome="' + dataChrome + '" href="https://twitter.com/' + this.props.account + '">Tweets by ' + this.props.account + '</a>';

    if (this.twttr == null) {
      SPComponentLoader.loadScript('//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', { globalExportsName: 'twttr' }).then((twttr?: any)=> {
        this.twttr = twttr;
      });
    }
    else {
      this.twttr.widgets.load();
    }
    }

     return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: innerHtml}}>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

webpart.ts:

```
export default class TwitterWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<ITwitterProps> {
public constructor(context?: IWebPartContext) {
    super();

    //Hack: to invoke correctly the onPropertyChange function outside this class
    //we need to bind this object on it first
    this.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged = this.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged.bind(this);
  }

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<ITwitterProperties> = React.createElement(

      Twitter,
      {
        httpClient: this.context.spHttpClient,
        siteUrl: this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl,
        listName: "Messages",//announcement2
        account: this.properties.account,
        autoLimit:this.properties.autoLimit,
        limit:this.properties.limit,
        header:this.properties.header, 
        footer:this.properties.footer,
        borders: this.properties.borders,
        scrollbars: this.properties.scrollbars, 
        width:this.properties.width,
        height:this.properties.height,
        transparent:this.properties.transparent,
        dark:this.properties.dark,
        linkColor:this.properties.linkColor,
        borderColor:this.properties.borderColor,
        description:this.properties.description
      }
    );
    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          displayGroupsAsAccordion: true,
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('account', {
                  label: strings.Account
                }),
                PropertyPaneToggle('autoLimit', {
                  label: strings.AutoLimit
                }),
                PropertyPaneSlider('limit', {
                  label: strings.Limit,
                  min: 1,
                  max: 1000,
                  step: 1
                }),
                PropertyPaneToggle('header', {
                  label: strings.Header
                }),
                PropertyPaneToggle('footer', {
                  label: strings.Footer
                }),
                PropertyPaneToggle('borders', {
                  label: strings.Borders
                }),
                PropertyPaneToggle('scrollbars', {
                  label: strings.Scrollbars
                })
              ]
            },
            {
              groupName: strings.LayoutGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('width', {
                  label: strings.Width
                }),
                PropertyPaneTextField('height', {
                  label: strings.Height
                }),
                PropertyPaneToggle('transparent', {
                  label: strings.Transparent
                }),
                PropertyFieldColorPicker('linkColor', {
                  label: strings.LinkColor,
                  initialColor: this.properties.linkColor,
                  onPropertyChange: this.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged,
                  properties: this.properties
                }),
                PropertyFieldColorPicker('borderColor', {
                  label: strings.BorderColor,
                  initialColor: this.properties.borderColor,
                  onPropertyChange: this.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged,
                  properties: this.properties
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

This is my [repo](https://github.com/y3n3rrr/SPFxAnnouncements). if you think its necessary,(webpart:twitter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at implementing `mobx` with your React webpart.

> React renders the application state by providing mechanisms to
>   translate it into a tree of renderable components. MobX provides the
>   mechanism to store and update the application state that React then
>   uses.

Reference - [Mobxjs](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx)

Here is one sample SPFx implementation that uses Mobx

Reference  link - [SPFx React Mobx](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-mobx) - currently on drop 5, but you can use it in RC 0 after making some necessary adjustments.

You will have to install the `Mobx` and its `react-bindings` as below:

```
npm install mobx --save
npm install mobx-react --save
```

After that in your tsx file, you need to make the below entries:

```
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';

import * as strings from 'reactMobxStrings';
import DefaultContainer from './containers/DefaultContainer';
import { IReactMobxWebPartProps } from './IReactMobxWebPartProps';
import twitter from './twitter';  //make necessary changes here
```

After that your class would look something as below, note this part is not totally accurate as I could not find twitter webpart in your git repository(please upload if possible) , make changes as necessary as per sample SPFx webpart :

```
export default class TwitterWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<ITwitterProps> { 
  private twitter = new twitter();

  public constructor(context: IWebPartContext) {
    super(context);
  }

  public render(): void {
    if (this.renderedOnce) { return; }

    const element  = (

      <Provider {...this.Twitter}>
      {
        httpClient: this.context.spHttpClient,
        siteUrl: this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl,
        listName: "Messages",//announcement2
        account: this.properties.account,
        autoLimit:this.properties.autoLimit,
        limit:this.properties.limit,
        header:this.properties.header, 
        footer:this.properties.footer,
        borders: this.properties.borders,
        scrollbars: this.properties.scrollbars, 
        width:this.properties.width,
        height:this.properties.height,
        transparent:this.properties.transparent,
        dark:this.properties.dark,
        linkColor:this.properties.linkColor,
        borderColor:this.properties.borderColor,
        description:this.properties.description
      }
      </Provider>
    );
    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);    
  }

  protected get disableReactivePropertyChanges() {
    return this.properties ? this.properties.disableReactive : false;
  }

  protected onPropertyChanged(propertyPath, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (!this.disableReactivePropertyChanges) {
      this.twitter.webpart.properties.set(propertyPath, newValue);
    }
  }

  protected onInit() {
    this.twitter.webpart.properties.clear();
    this.twitter.webpart.properties.merge(this.properties as {});

    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }

  protected onAfterPropertyPaneChangesApplied() {
    this.twitter.webpart.properties.merge(this.properties as {});
  }

  //code here
}
```

Also read this link - [Building SharePoint Framework Client Side Web Parts with non-reactive property pane](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-parts-non-reactive-property-pane/)

Comment: welcome , FYI i cloned your repository , couldnt find twitter webpart ? did you publish it ?

Comment: Yes. it was belong to other branch but I merge it with master. Can you check it now ?